# Shoud I celebrate finishing Probationary Period (Probezeit)

Tags: germany, fulltime

In the company I finished my probationary period. Actually I want to share my happiness with my colleagues by eating some biscuits and drinking in the company. However I am not sure

- How react the people this event? Actually I have a fear that people could misunderstand me. For instance, they (may) think that limonik tries to make up to her boss -   ingratiate her boss - by organizing this activity. Or are such activities typical in working environment?
- If I organize this what should I write in my invitation mail?

Advance thanks for all recommendations and idea.

Comment: Depends heavily on your company culture.

Comment: Do you want to organize this on company grounds? Or as a personal affair in some other location?

Comment: @Magisch I know. Therefore I tried to find a tag company_culture. However I did not found. How could I learn / observe the company culture?

Comment: @Erik Actually in the company in my office which I share two others. Because I have no strong relationship with my colleagues that we meet outside in a cafe or some other location

Comment: Ask some of the people you work with is probably the easiest way to find out.

Comment: I celebrate nigh on _everything_ I reasonably can (by bringing pastries or such) -- sometimes even "first Tuesday of the week" -- because it's a good way to get "brownie points" with both coworkers and (immediate) management. There are practically no downsides except expectations of regular pastries...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically you don't celebrate the end of your *Probezeit*. However, it is more common to celebrate your *Einstand* [[1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstand_%28Feier%29)], i.e., your joining the team or company. If you haven't done that already, you could give that as the reason for a small celebration and mention that you do it now since you know you are going to stay.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you check how personal birthdays are celebrated and do something similar.

It's a nice gesture, but publicly you should treat the successful end of your *Probezeit* as something that was bound to happen anyway. Like a birthday. It comes without any effort on your side and is celebrated. An unusual celebration of the end of your *Probezeit* looks as if failure was something you thought was possible. Don't give that impression.

If you want to really celebrate this because it's special for you, do so in private with some good friends.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Uh, correct, I blame that on the lack of coffee :)

Comment: one could even word it as a celebration of the first X months (6 I would guess) in the company, not even mentionning the Probezeit. This way it even sounds like some kind of birthday or anniversary.

Comment: @Puzzled you are right. "Celebration" sounds like a party. Therefore I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

As nvoigt said a big celebration could be a bit too much.

I think that if you really want to do a celebration, it must only include the team you work with. Say to your direct manager that you would like to do something like that and ask what could be done. It will mainly depends of your work environment.

Maybe you could come with fresh bakeries, and says a little thanks for them to be welcoming and that you feel (great/at ease) and ready to work with them for the few (months/years) to come.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to organize a small get together on office premises, the best first step is probably to talk to either HR or your manager. They can fill you in not only on the company culture, but also and what the company considers acceptable or even allowed.

Don't send out invitations to invite people to an event before you have permission from the location owner to hold it there. The last thing you want is to tell people "Let's meet Friday after hours" only to get a company-wide reply "You're not allowed to host meetings after hours.

In addition, they can probably tell you what other people might do, or what is expected. Some companies have regular end-of-week drinks, for example. In this case, it might be possible to have your celebration by sponsoring one. It'll help ensure a decent turn-out, too.